# JWPlayer is not playing mp4 file

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using the latest JWPlayer for my website for an option to play mp3 audio and mp4 video.The audio is playing fine but in case of mp4 video it is displaying an error "Error loading media,cannot play file".Any idea why this is happenning?
I can assure that the video path is perfectly okey.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?